# How to persist additional claims and tokens from external providers in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, owin

I have an app that is written on the top of an old ASP.NET MVC 5 framework using `C#`. I want to enable OpenIdConnect authentication to allow my users to authenticate using a private OpenId server.

I was able to add the OpenId external provider using [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/) project. Here is how configured the OpenId authentication provider

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Authority = "openid-server-domain.com",
    RedeemCode = true,
    SaveTokens = true,
    ResponseType = "code",
    ClientId = "***",
    ClientSecret = "***",
    RedirectUri = "https://localhost:55555/connect/redirect",
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = "/disconnect/sign-out",
    Scope = "openid profile email"
});
```

As you can see above, I am requesting access to the profile and email scopes which should give me info like `username`, `email` and some others. I want to add the data sent by the OpenId server as claims to the user.

**Question**
How to persist additional claims and tokens from external providers in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by subscribing to the `SecurityTokenValidated` event and call the `userinfo` API on the server. I am not sure if this is the best approach.

```
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                Authority = "openid-server-domain.com",
                RedeemCode = true,
                SaveTokens = true,
                ResponseType = "code",
                ClientId = "***",
                ClientSecret = "***",
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:55555/connect/redirect",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "/disconnect/sign-out",
                Scope = "openid profile email"
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        var id = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                        var client = new HttpClient()
                        {
                            BaseAddress = new Uri("openid-server-domain.com"),
                        };

                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);

                        var response = await client.GetAsync("connect/userinfo");

                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                            var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenIdUserInfo>(data);

                            if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(info.Name))
                            {
                                id.AddClaim(new Claim("name", info.Name));
                            }
                        }

                        context.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(id, context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                    }
                }
            });
```